# How is the definition of $n$-qubit Pauli group derived?

Tags: mathematics, pauli-gates

The authors give the following definition for the Pauli group in the paper [Averaged circuit eigenvalue sampling](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.05803).

> The n-qubit Pauli group $P_n$ consists of n-fold tensor products of single-qubit Pauli operators labeled as follows. Let $\mathbf{a}$ be a 2n-bit string $\mathbf{a}=a_1a_2\ldots a_{2n}$ and write $P_\mathbf{a} = i^{\mathbf{a}^T \Upsilon \mathbf{a}} \prod_{j=1}^{n} X^{\mathbf{a}_{2j-1}}_j Z^{\mathbf{a}_{2j}}_j$, where $X_j$ and $Z_j$ are single-qubit Paulis acting on qubit $j$ and $$\Upsilon=\bigoplus^n_{k=1}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ is such that $P_{\mathbf{a}}$ is always hermitian.

How is this definition of the Pauli group derived? Is there a similar way to define the Clifford group?

Comment: Have you tried working out a few examples. This is quite straightforward way of defining the Pauli group.

Comment: @AbdullahKhalid yeah, the definition itself makes sense. I'm more curious as it where it comes from.

Comment: Pauli group is named after Wolfgang Pauli. If you are asking for the original reference, this [reference](https://neutrino.kek.jp/seesaw/proc/articles/01_nishijima.ps) suggests that Pauli first invented the idea of such transformations in 1957. I don't know when his ideas were refined into the nice present form. See also this [reference](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/25/4/738/227903/The-relationship-between-finite-groups-and?redirectedFrom=fulltext) This also talks about Clifford algebras.

Comment: Will this help: the definition is merely the following Pauli group ignoring the phase: $$G_n\equiv \{\pm I,\pm iI,\pm X,\pm iX,\pm Y,\pm iY,\pm Z,\pm iZ\}^{\otimes n}.$$ Or more technically, it's the quotient group $G_n/\left\{ \pm I,\pm iI \right\} ^{\otimes n}$. As for the bitstring notation, it's similar to the idea called check matrix which you can find in Section *The stabilizer formalism* of Nielsen and Chuang's book.